# RaisePostBackEvent not firing

Tags: asp.net, postback

I have a custom control that implements IPostBackEventHandler. Some client-side events invoke __doPostBack(controlID, eventArgs).

The control is implemented in two different user controls. In one control, RaisePostBackEvent is fired on the server-side when `__doPostBack` is invoked. In the other control, RaisePostBackEvent is never invoked. I checked the `__EVENTTARGET` parameter and it does match the ClientID of the control... where else might I look to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of ways this can fall apart.  Are you adding the control to the page dynamically in code behind?  If so alot of times your UniqueID can be off - even though the client id's are equal.  Do you have a code sample that might demonstrate what you're doing?

Comment: (Moved to comment) - Well I feel kind of stupid... it was a simple problem - I thought the UniqueID of the control matched __EVENTARGS but due to some JavaScript goofiness on my part, it had one $ where an underscore should have been. It was an extremely long UniqueID so easy to overlook.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that it is indeed a derivation of the UserControl class, not the WebControl one.
This one has had me by surprise many times. If you need to use WebControl for the styling, you need to let your control implement INamingContainer. (Don't worry, its a marker interface)

So..

```
public class MyControl : UserControl {}
```

Or

```
public class MyControl : WebControl, INamingContainer {}
```